# Evaluating read variable on the same Line in a bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script

I try to get the value this command in a bash script returns but, It seem not to be returning anything

```
rr=$(read -p Enter -r)

echo "Is $rr"
read -p "java archive detected, Enter Y to download it again, N to continue $nl" -r
if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]] && [[ $(read -p Enter -r) == "Y" ]]; then

        echo "Y entered $REPLY"
        break;

    elif [[  $REPLY =~ ^[Nn]$  ]]; then

        echo "java Archive was extracted successfully to $java8Dir $nl"

    fi
```

Answer (score 4):

That's because you are running the `read` in a command substitution (`$()`). There's no need for that. Just use:

```
read -p Enter -r rr
echo "Is $rr"
```

The `var=$(command)` syntax will set the value of `var` to whatever is returned by `command`. The `read` builtin doesn't return anything (apart from its exit status but that's not relevant here), so your variable remains empty. The syntax of `read` is `read VAR` and it will set the value of `$VAR`.

Answer (score 1):

the proper syntax for `read` is

> read [-ers] [-a aname] [-d delim] [-i text] [-n nchars] [-N nchars] [-p
>         prompt] [-t timeout] [-u fd] [name ...]

(from `man bash`)

- first line sould be `read -p Enter -r rr` (you realy need to unescape backslash ? )
- inner test should read

  ```
  if ... && [[ "$(read -p Enter R ; echo $R )" == "Y"  ]] ; tehn
  ```

Comment: Thanks, This worked for me, but what about `test [[ "$(read -p 'Do you wish to install gtodo $nl' R) echo $R" =~ "Y" ]] && (sudo apt-get install gtodo) || (echo "gtodo not installed")`

Answer (score 0):

The command `read -p Enter -r` will place the value of what an user type inside the variable $REPLY (in Bash). So, this will work:

```sh
$ read -p Enter: -r
Enter:hello
$ echo "$REPLY"
hello
```

therefore, if you want the input of the user in var rr, do this:

```sh
$ read -p "Enter: " -r rr
Enter: hello
$ echo "$rr"
hello
```

Or, as one line:

```sh
$ read -p "Enter: " -r rr; echo "$rr"
Enter: hello
hello
```

All you need to do (in the script) to read the variable, and then print it, is:

```sh
read -p "Enter : " -r rr
echo "Is $rr"
```